# Humanoid whose mother died at his birth becomes a warship captain

Tags: story-identification, aliens, powers

I read a book in the 1976-1977 timeframe that was about this humanoid. He was born prematurely on another planet and killed his mother in the process. The early birth indicated he was highly evolved for his species, and possibly a messiah. He grows up without much love, because his father blames him for his mother's death, and he ends up becoming the captain of a small, extremely powerful, warship. They go into a Armageddon type battle and are able to turn the tide of the battle, but eventually get hit.

There was a sequel and there is another of his race who also was born early and actually is a messiah. He ends up on earth, I think. This is as much as I remember. Loved the book as a teenager and would love to find it again please help.